# Graph, ToolTip, and Labeled: How to make a swanky graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, tooltip

## Problem

I do not understand Mathematica's Documentation for `Labeled`, `VertexLabels`, `VertexRenderingFunction`, etc

I want to make a `Graph` that has `Tooltip` enabled for verticies and edges, has `PopupWindow` enabled for the verticies, has different colors for edges of different type, different colors for specific verticies, and smaller arrows, etc.

### Example

I have a list of index pairs, e.g.

```
indexList = {
{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},
{4,2},{4,1},
{5,2}
};
```

Just for purpose of this example lets say I have a list with labels for my verticies and edges

```
vertexLabels = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
edgeLabels = {"e1","e2","e3","e4","e5","e6"};
```

### Convert index pairs to directed edges

```
directedEdges = Table[indexList[[i]][[1]] \[DirectedEdge] indexList[[i]][[2]],{i,1,Length[indexList]}];
```

### Apply `Tooltip` to directed edges

```
directedEdgesTooltip = Table[Tooltip[directedEdges[[i]], edgeLabels[[i]]],{i,1,Length[directedEdges]}];
```

But supposedily one can use `Labeled`

```
directedEdgesLabeled = Table[Labeled[directedEdges[[i]], edgeLabels[[i]],Tooltip],{i,1,Length[directedEdges]}];
```

Calling `Graph` on this works-ish
    Graph[directedEdgesLabeled]

But that *isn't* how it **should** work.
Supposedily I should call

```
Graph[directedEdges,EdgeLabels -> directedEdgesLabeled]
```

But that doesn't work. As you'll see this goes on for Verticies too.

### Apply `Tooltip` to Verticies

```
verticiesLabeled = Table[Labeled[Range[5][[i]], vertexLabels[[i]],Tooltip],{i,1,Length[Range[5]]}];
```

So lets try again

```
Graph[directedEdges, VertexLabels -> verticiesLabeled]
```

Oh darn... that doesn't work.

What about using `Tooltip` on the directedEdges? Well that works, if you only want the vertex labeled.

### Note

Nesting `Labeled` does not work

```
Labeled[Labeled[1, "a", Tooltip] \[DirectedEdge] Labeled[2, "b", Tooltip], "e1", Tooltip]
```

## Question

So please someone tell me how to do this. We haven't even got into adding `PopupWindow` (which I have tried a myraid of methods for).

Comment: Just noting that `GraphPlot` is the old way of plotting graphs and has mostly been replaced by `Graph` since version 8.0.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I thought GraphPlot was the new way of doing so, as Head[Graph] is Graph and Head[GraphPlot] is Graphic...

Comment: Why do you think the head has any relevance to this?  If you want to convert a Graph to pure Graphics, use Show.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't... it is that Mathematica is all about standardization of langauge, which is why I though `GraphPlot` was brought into existance... Anyway using `Graph` with the graph I described above does not work, which is why I gravitated towards `GraphPlot` because that actually produced a graphic

Comment: Look up the correct syntax for `Graph`.  It's not the same.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have been and let me tell you I am getting to feel very stupid. Following the documentations guidelines for `Labeled`  etc just causes errors

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  Can you give a simple and clear example where you state how the graph should be displayed?  Tooltips are added either as wrappers or as placements in VertexLabels or EdgeLabels.  Styles can be handled separately.  `Graph[{Tooltip[1, "foo"], Tooltip[2, "bar"], 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 
  Tooltip[2 <-> 3, "this is an edge"], 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 1}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Yellow}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs just updated the question to make it more clear. I am working with an amount of nodes that I am not going to hard code labels in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to getting `Labeled` Edges and Verticies

1.) Do not use `Labeled`, use `Placed`. See below:

```
makeEdgeLabels[directedEdges_] := 
 Table[directedEdges[[i]] -> 
   Placed[getEdgeLabel[directedEdges[[i]]], Tooltip], {i, 1, 
   Length[directedEdges]}]

makeVertexLabels[indexList_] := Module[
  {iL = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[indexList]]},
  Return[
   Table[iL[[i]] -> Placed[proteinNames[[iL[[i]]]], Tooltip], {i, 1, 
     Length[iL]}]
   ]
  ]


Graph[directedEdges,EdgesLabels-> makeEdgeLabels[directedEdges],VertexLabels->makeVertexLabels[directedEdges]]
```